# COM class factory error when calling Crystal Reports in a .NET DLL which is being called via COM from a VB6 application. Works fine from a .NET app

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, com, vb6

This is a strange one that I can't seem to get working. I have an old VB6 application that calls a .NET framework DLL through COM which in turn is calling the Crystal Reports .NET SDK. The line causing the issue is

```
new ReportDocument();
```

If I use this DLL through a normal .NET application, this works perfectly and the Crystal Report displays as intended, however one I go to call this through COM in the VB6 application, this following error comes up:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {D7F5D7C3-B06C-4CAC-BC47-A06E66D2EE9B} failed due to the following error: 8007045a
```

I've read everything I can from others who have experienced the same thing but still cannot get it working. I have the platform target in the .NET DLL set to x86 and have tried both reinstalling Crystal Reports as well as manually registering the Crystal libraries but am still getting the same issue.

Is there anything else I can try here to get this working?

Comment: How did you register the .NET COM DLL on the target machine, i.e. did you use the right version (32-bit) of RegAsm.exe to do this?

Comment: Is that CLSID one of yours? Or is it from some other component?

Comment: @HelO'Ween I have the DLL ticked as com visible in the project settings, so it automatically gets registered when I build it, and I can confirm it builds because I can attach the debugger to the VB6 application and have it hit a breakpoint in the DLL code.

Comment: @StayOnTarget That CLSID is the crystal object ID I believe

Comment: At this point I would monitor the app in Process Monitor and see if that gives any clues to what happens at the point where that error is generated. ProcMon is very detailed but often the best way to get insight into these kinds of problems.

Comment: Another idea would be to see if you can repro the problem on another PC or not. That might help to narrow down an environment problem.